# Springboot application.properties file not working to use default & custom properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration

So I have followed almost all tutorials/examples and stack overflow questions but I still can't seem to get my application.properties file to be able to fill in values in an ExternalConfig class I have created.

My application properties class file is located in src/main/resources and looks like this

```
app.developerName = "f21ad267-e241-4ed0-8943-721fa90bcf3a"
spring.boot.config.developerName = "f21ad267-e241-4ed0-8943-721fa90bcf3a"
server.port=9000
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

My purpose built External Config class looks like this

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.boot.config")
@Component
public class ExternalConfig {

private String developerName;

public String getDeveloperName() {
    return developerName;
}

public void setDeveloperName(String developerName) {
    this.developerName = developerName;
}   
}
```

Finally my Springboot main class looks like this

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ExternalConfig.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootMain implements CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
ExternalConfig externalConfig;

@Bean
ResourceConfig resourceConfig() {
    return new ResourceConfig().registerClasses(ExternalConfig.class, Version1Api.class, Paypal.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootMain.class);
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(externalConfig.getDeveloperName());

}  
}
```

Every time I run the code or debug it, the ExternalClass and it's variables are always null.

I am running out of ideas and methods to try do this an alternative way. Am I missing something in my pom.xml?

Comment: When I try your provided example code, it works. What is your Spring Boot version? And is your application.properties file called `application.properties` exactly?

Comment: Check out the following links: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation a guide that describes how you should define your "@Configuration" class and use "@Value".  The corresponding github link to the code: https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-boot-properties

Comment: You are aware that you have multiple instances of the `ExternalConfig`? You either do `@Component` with `@ConfigurationProperties` or `@EnableConfigurationProperties` with `@ConfigurationProperties`. You also have a fresh instance in JAX-RS which isn't coupled to the instance in Spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These 2 changes may help:

1. Remove the blank spaces next to '=' symbol in the application.properties file
2. Remove the word 'prefix=' from the @ConfigurationProperties annotation.

More information:

A very good article with working code on extracting the application properties.

https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-configurationproperties-example/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define the bean differently

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.boot.config")
public class ExternalConfig {
```

Comment: `@ConfigurationProperties` works with an `@Component` as well.